# Test angular directive - angular.element.css

Tags: angularjs, testing, jasmine

I want write test for angular directive method in jasmine. How to test toHaveBeenCalled for .css method in the following code?
I try to create spy for this method but always got `Expected spy css to have been called.`. Is it good idea to test css method call?

Directive method to test:

```
scope.contentPadding = () => {
  const bars = angular.element(element[0].querySelectorAll('.intro'));
  if (bars.length > 0) {
    const bar = angular.element(bars[bars.length - 1]);
    bar.parent().css('padding-top', `${bar[0].offsetHeight - 10}px`);
  }
};
```

My test implementation:

```
describe('test', function() {
  var $rootScope,
      $compile,
      $scope,
      $window,
      element;

  function compileDirective() {
    var html = angular.element(`
      <div my-directive-name>
        <div class="section">
          <div class="intro"></div>
        </div>
      </div>`);

      element = $compile(html)($scope);
      $scope.$digest();
    }

    beforeEach(function() {
      angular.mock.module('my-directive-name');

      inject(function(_$rootScope_, _$compile_, _$window_) {
        $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
        $compile = _$compile_;
        $window = _$window_;

        $scope = $rootScope.$new();
        compileDirective();
      });
    });

  describe('padding', function() {
    it('adds top padding', function() {
      var el = angular.element(element[0].querySelector('.section'));
      spyOn(el, 'css');
      $scope.contentPadding();
      $scope.$digest();
      expect(el.css).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Show us your current test.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure you're spying on the angular element:

```
it('adds top padding' function () {
   var element = angular.element(....);

    spyOn(element, 'css');

    // Trigger padding here

    expect(element.css).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for reply!

I implemented test with your code but sill got response 'Expected spy css to have been called.'

I completed my post about test implementation.

Comment: be sure to force the digest cycle. using "scope.$digest();"  Try placing it after scope.contentPadding();

Comment: With $scope.$digest() after method call result is these same.